# c# - itext7 - How to add text to new page?

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm creating Pdfs using itext7. It allows me to add paragraphs to first page but I'm not sure how can I add content to second page. If I create Canvas after calling AddNewPage() then it works fine, but it doesn't work when I use a paragraph and I add it to the document. Thanks for help. In my example, firstPageText and secondPageText will be displayed on first page:

```
protected void CreatePdf(string filePath, string firstPageText, string secondPageText)
   {
       PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filePath);
       PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
       Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);

       doc.Add(new Paragraph(firstPageText));
       pdfDocument.AddNewPage();
       doc.Add(new Paragraph(secondPageText)); 

       doc.Close();
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in [chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks). Allow me to copy a snippet of that tutorial:

> If we had used an `AreaBreak` of type `NEXT_PAGE`, a new page would have been started; see figure 2.11.
>
> [image]
>
> In the
>   [JekyllHydeV5](/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-2#1899-c02e09_jekyllhydev5.java)
>   example, we changed a single line:
>
> ```
> AreaBreak nextPage = new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE);
> ```
>
> Instead of skipping to the next column, iText now skips to the next
>   page.
>
> > By default, the newly created page will have the same page size as
> >     the current page. If you want iText to create a page of another
> >     size, you can use the constructor that accepts a `PageSize` object as
> >     a parameter. For instance: `new AreaBreak(PageSize.A3)`.
>
> There's also an `AreaBreak` of type `LAST_PAGE`. This `AreaBreakType`
>   is to be used when switching between different renderers.

It surprises me that you'd do this:

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph(firstPageText));
pdfDocument.AddNewPage();
doc.Add(new Paragraph(secondPageText));
```

While the documented way is to do it like this:

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph(firstPageText));
doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
doc.Add(new Paragraph(secondPageText));
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I have just started working with iText7